# How to use Word Com Application in Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, com, xampp

I'm use Laravel 5.4, PHP 7.1 on XAMPP.
In advance I will say that the PHPWord does not suit me.
I Want use Com Application in Laravel controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Library\NCLNameCaseRu;
use DB;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function index() {


        $debtid = DB::select(
            "EXECUTE dbo.SP_JudgApplicationFl @DebtID = ?", array('38')
        );



        foreach ($debtid as $v) {
            print_r($v->AccountNumber);
            $word = new \COM("Word.Application", null, CP_UTF8);
            $word->Visible = 0;
            $word->Documents->Add("C:/xampp/htdocs/myfile.dotx");
        }

    }

}
```

But i get error

> Class 'COM' not found

I successfully connected a class "NCLNameCaseRu" with composer autoload. But this i have specific folder with class.
How can I do the same with COM application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core.you have to add COM support in php.ini:

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Otherwise you will see this in your error log: Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found

The extension is included with php 5.4.5 for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Im'sorry, i forget add

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

in php.ini
All work fine.